# How to parse dynamic json in android with retrofit 2 using annotations

Tags: java, android, json, gson, retrofit2

I have a JSON structure which I want to parse using retrofit 2 (@Expose). Below I have mentioned the JSON. Need help to parse it using dynamic annotations.

```
{
  "status": 1,
  "message": "success",
  "data" : [
    {
      "type": 1,
      "heading": "",
      "description": "",
      "created_on": 141123213,
      "author_id": 123,
      "author_name": "some name",
      "author_pic": "some_pic",
      "read_time": "3.1 min",
      "post_pic_url": "",
      "post_web_url": "",
      "isLiked": false,
      "isSaved": false,
      "totalLikes": 12
   },
   {
      "type": 2,
      "author_id": 123,
      "author_name": "some name",
      "author_pic": "some pic",
      "author_about": "",
      "tags":[
        "travel", "weekends"
      ],
      "isFollowing": false
   },
   {
     "type": 3,
     "poll_name": "Some name",
     "poll_options": [
       "opt1", "opt2", "opt3"
     ],
     "author_id": 123,
     "author_name": "some name",
     "author_pic": "some pic",
     "isLiked": true,
     "isFollowing": false
   },
   {
     "type": 4,
     "ad_url": "url",
     "ad_pic": "pic"
   },
   {
     "type": 5,
     "tags": [
       "tag1", "tag2", "tag3"
     ]
   }
  ]
 }
```

I have updated the JSON structure with all 5 types.

Comment: dynamic annotations means each time json structure will change?

Comment: Did you try anything before asking here ?

Comment: Of course, I tried creating a model with all the items mentioned in the JSON, which works but is not the best solution I want to go with. Looking for some efficient method

Comment: @Lingeshwaran dynamic annotations means my data jsonarray will have 5 types which contains different keys for each type. Now I created 5 different models for each type but dont know how to communicate those models to retrofit using gson

Comment: @ketan268 post the complete json structure we will see, i.e include all the  5 types

Comment: @ketan268 What JSON library are you using?

Comment: @Lingeshwaran I have updated the JSON structure in the question. Please check

Comment: @LyubomyrShaydariv I am using GSON for serialization as retrofit supports this library out of box.

Comment: @ketan268 post your retrofit code by how you parsing.

Answer (score 1):

1 Use Retrofit convert 
  example GSON convert

2 Add com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson in gradle  file 
3 Add converter factory in Retrofit object

Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(Ws_Url)
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .client(clientBuilder.build())
            .build();

4 Create Model class for Your response 
  Use below link to generate model class
  http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/

Comment: That service cannot handle polymorphic JSONs.

Comment: Yeah, this will not help as the items in the model class is supposed to be different according to the JSON structure I mentinoed. And if I create on model class with all the json items then it throws exception as it does not find a KEY for other json array item.

Answer (score 0):

Retrofit does not do serialization and deserialization, but Gson does.
You might want to use [RuntimeTypeAdapterFactory](https://github.com/google/gson/blob/master/extras/src/main/java/com/google/gson/typeadapters/RuntimeTypeAdapterFactory.java) from the Google Gson extras package.
It's not published at artifact repositories, and you can simply copy the code to your project.
If type adapters are somewhat complex (as they work with JSON streams), you might find `JsonDeserializer<T>` easier to use and probably maintain (they work with JSON trees consuming some more memory, but it's the only way to go here anyway).

Define your mappings similar to:

```java
// There might be no the common root, and target lists might be parameterized with Object, but it's up to you
abstract class Element {

    final int type = Integer.valueOf(0);

    // Since the number of types is really finite, we can define all known types in one place
    private Element() {
    }

    static final class Type1Element
            extends Element {

        // the rest of properties go here

        // Gson does not need constructors, neither we do (at least public ones)
        private Type1Element() {
        }

    }

    static final class Type2Element
            extends Element {

        // the rest of properties go here

        private Type2Element() {
        }

    }

}
```

```java
final class Response<T> {

    final int status = Integer.valueOf(0);
    final String message = null;
    final T data = null;

}
```

Now the deserializer itself:

```java
final class ElementJsonDeserializer
        implements JsonDeserializer<Element> {

    private static final JsonDeserializer<Element> elementJsonDeserializer = new ElementJsonDeserializer();

    private ElementJsonDeserializer() {
    }

    // The deserializer is essentially a singleton, but we hide away this fact making sure that only 1 instance exists
    static JsonDeserializer<Element> getElementJsonDeserializer() {
        return elementJsonDeserializer;
    }

    @Override
    public Element deserialize(final JsonElement jsonElement, final Type type, final JsonDeserializationContext context)
            throws JsonParseException {
        final int typeCode = jsonElement.getAsJsonObject().getAsJsonPrimitive("type").getAsInt();
        // Simple dispatching here
        // RuntimeTypeAdapterFactory basically does the same
        switch ( typeCode ) {
        case 1:
            return context.deserialize(jsonElement, Type1Element.class);
        case 2:
            return context.deserialize(jsonElement, Type2Element.class);
        default:
            throw new JsonParseException("Unrecognized type: " + typeCode);
        }
    }

}
```

Now get it all working together (`response.json` is your JSON document resource):

```java
private static final Type type = new TypeToken<Response<List<Element>>>() {
}.getType();

private static final Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
        .registerTypeAdapter(Element.class, getElementJsonDeserializer())
        .create();

public static void main(final String... args)
        throws IOException {
    try ( final JsonReader jsonReader = getPackageResourceJsonReader(Q43802350.class, "response.json") ) {
        final Response<List<Element>> response = gson.fromJson(jsonReader, type);
        response.data
                .stream()
                .map(Element::getClass)
                .map(Class::getSimpleName)
                .forEach(System.out::println);
    }
}
```

Output:

> Type1Element
>   Type2Element

Of course, don't forget to register the `gson` instance with `GsonConverterFactory.create(gson)` in your `Retrofit` builder.