# Read JSON file via Gson when using a list of objects

Tags: java, json, gson

I try to explain my situation as best as possible. I want to read a JSON file with Gson which contains a list of objects. This object is the Base class as I have several objects which extend it.

```
{ 
    "name":"Test", 
    "url":"http://test.test", 
    "script":[ 
        { "actionId":1, "actionType":"click", "id":"testId", "redirect" : "http://google.de" },
        { "actionId":2, "actionType":"write", "id":"testId2", "content":"testContent" } 
    ] 
}
```

The base class is called `ScriptElement`, and it contains some values every child object needs too. `ScriptInput` and `ScriptClickable` are the children.
If I convert my list to JSON, I get a well generated JSON file. But when I read the JSON file and convert it back to the object, it only contains `ScriptElement` objects and is missing the additional information of `ScriptInput` and `ScriptClickable`.

Comment: you can atleaste show us the json file !

Comment: `{
  "name":"Test",
  "url":"http://test.test",
  "script":[
    {
      "actionId":1,
      "actionType":"click",
      "id":"testId",
      "redirect" : "http://google.de"
    },
    {
      "actionId":2,
      "actionType":"write",
      "id":"testId2",
      "content":"testContent"
    }
  ]
}`

i tried to add it to the main text, but i get permamently the message that the code is not valid. dont know why.

Comment: can you edit your post instade fof put your comment ?

Comment: like i said, i can't. the system tells me that my code contains error and it cant be added.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a classic case: it happens because Gson does not have any clue on how `ScriptElement` and `actionType` values are related to each other. You have just to tell Gson how these could be mapped.

For simplicity, I'm assuming your mappings are something like these:

```java
final class Response {
    final String name = null;
    final URL url = null;
    final List<ScriptElement> script = null;
}
```

```java
abstract class ScriptElement {
    final int actionId = Integer.valueOf(0);
    final String id = null;
}
```

```java
final class ScriptClickable extends ScriptElement {
    final URL redirect = null;
}
```

```java
final class ScriptInput extends ScriptElement {
    final String content = null;
}
```

Now, just register a `JsonDeserializer` to produce a `ScriptElement` depending on the `actionType` property value.

```
private static final Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
        .registerTypeAdapter(ScriptElement.class, (JsonDeserializer<ScriptElement>) (jsonElement, type, context) -> {
            final String actionType = jsonElement.getAsJsonObject().getAsJsonPrimitive("actionType").getAsString();
            switch ( actionType ) {
            case "click":
                return context.deserialize(jsonElement, ScriptClickable.class);
            case "write":
                return context.deserialize(jsonElement, ScriptInput.class);
            default:
                throw new JsonParseException("Unrecognized action type: " + actionType);
            }
        })
        .create();
```

As you can see, the only thing you have to do is:

- Get the action type from the JSON tree.
- Dispatch the action type value to the downstream deserialization context with a proper class reference (let Gson just do it what it's the best at).

Once you have done it, you can test it:

```java
try ( final JsonReader jsonReader = getPackageResourceJsonReader(Q43843846.class, "test.json") ) {
    final Response response = gson.fromJson(jsonReader, Response.class);
    for ( final ScriptElement element : response.script ) {
        if ( element instanceof ScriptClickable ) {
            final ScriptClickable clickable = (ScriptClickable) element;
            System.out.println(clickable.redirect);
        } else if ( element instanceof ScriptInput ) {
            final ScriptInput input = (ScriptInput) element;
            System.out.println(input.content);
        } else {
            throw new AssertionError(element);
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

> http://google.de
>   testContent

See more on polymorphic objects deserialization:

- [How to determine class of object from GSON parse?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43825103/how-to-determine-class-of-object-from-gson-parse/43825683#43825683)
- [How to parse dynamic json in android with retrofit 2 using annotations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43802350/how-to-parse-dynamic-json-in-android-with-retrofit-2-using-annotations/43804296#43804296)

Comment: i was thinking to use something similar, but i though there would be a solution which is more "integrated" into gson.

but thank you very much for your help. :) i will test it.

Comment: @Marco No, there is nothing like that in the core Gson. Consider Gson is a sort of a constructor that has trivial cases integrated only.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, well based on the json structure make a class with these attributes

```
public class User{
private String name;
private String url;
private ArrayList<Script>script;
}
public class Script{
private int actionId;
private String actionType;
private String id;
private String redirect;
}
```

Now when you want to parse it by gson 
You should create a reference from user class
pull the json from the file to a myJsonString variable which will you create

```
User user=new Gson().fromJson(myJsonString,User.class);
```

Comment: Hello, your user class is correct, it looks close to mine.

but Script is just a BaseClass, all elements in this list are Child classes which extends from Script. Like this

`public class ScriptClickable extends ScriptElement {

    @SerializedName("redirect")
    @Expose
    private String redirect;

    @Override
    public boolean execute() {
        //execute the code which is important for a scriptClickable
        System.out.println("Doing a button click");
        return true;
    }
}`

Comment: the reason why i use child classes is the "execute" method. based on the script class it does something different.

Comment: What do you mean ! i made the script class based on your script structure, it will not work otherwise

Comment: what is the execute method ?

Comment: Your elements should be exactly the same name with the json structure, otherwise it will not work

Comment: i know that my names need to be the same, but you probably missed the second element in the array of script, it is not the same like first one. instead of "redirect", it contains "content". these are two different object, which both extends from Script.

for your question, the execute function is supposed to do some tasks, based on the information in the script object. 
this is also the reason why i can't directly use Script. as each child element, is doing something different in the execute method.

Kind regards

Comment: okay then :) you can edit it , i just did give you a solution

Comment: I am sorry, i don't want to be rude, but this is sadly not a solution for me.

The List script is declared with the Object Type Script, this is correct and i am doing it the same way.

But the objects i store in there. are from Types like InputScript and ClickScript. which are children of Script.

Comment: if you have any other elements you have to add it to the class, then the others will be null 
add redirect attribute , write attribute
if one of them is not present then it will be null

Comment: why should i add any other element to the base class? that does not make sense, and breaks the sense of extending and interfaces. sorry but i don't see the point on this.

Comment: to match json structure :D 
Gson looks at what are the attributes in the json structure then it assigns the matches attributes between class and json structure 
any other elements not included with json response, the class attributes which are not  in the json  will be null